# Excel IFS statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Im using this formular:

```
=IFS(($B$10*B11)>20;"20";($B$10*B11)<20;B10*B11;B11=1;"")
```

But the line:

```
($B$10*B11)<20;B10*B11
```

Overwrites the line:

```
B11=1;"")
```

The line:

```
($B$10*B11)<20;B10*B11
```

Should say if the result is less than 20 and not equal to 1..

If the result is 1, it should run the last statement. How do I do that?

Comment: Put it first. It resolves in order.

Comment: Just make `B11=1` logical test 1 or 2 instead of logical test 3.  Can you see why?

Comment: Oh I see, works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @Jonas Larsen kindly share the answer in the answer tab. So we can remove this Q from SO unanswered list. (: